# Django form validation for a list of unknown strings

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am working an API with Django REST framework. One of my API endpoints accepts the following post request:

```
{
    "tokens": ["biemnxci92j3kd", "xjcivjd23djcisd"],
    ...
}
```

I want to use Django form to validate the parameters of this request. Here is my current form:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    processors = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
    # other stuff
    ...
```

My problem is that the `MultipleChoiceField` requires me to provide a list of accepted choices, but the strings I accept have random values and I do not know their values beforehand. So validating this form always gives me an error. I thought of several possible solutions, but none of them seemed to work:

1. Use another form field -- I cannot find another field that can be used to represent (and validate) a list of strings.
2. Create my own custom validator -- This somehow still requires me to define the field as a multiple choice field beforehand, I'm not sure how to create my own custom string list field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's an API and you probably don't even need to render the form with `{{ form }}` you can just remove the field completely, extend the `clean` method, and validate the data directly.

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):

    def clean(self):
        super(TestForm, self).clean()

        if 'tokens' in self.data:
            if your_logic_to_validate() is False:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid tokens')

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Even if you do need to render the form you would just render the HTML yourself instead of relying on `{{ form }}` and `{{ form.tokens }}`. You should be able to loop `form.data.tokens` to build a multi select and set them all to selected (or render no options if no data is bound).